# Application not loaded after upgrade from React-navigation 4 to React-Navigation 6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

after upgrade from React-navigation 4 to React-navigation 6 the default imports cause undefined errors when used for assignments.

The Application uses expo, Expo SDK version is 44.

[This error occurs when opening the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ9rh.png)

[Application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHOyQ.jpg)

RoutesNavigators.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import ConfigsLoading from './screens/commons/configs_loading';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const RoutesNavigator = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="ConfigsLoading" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="ConfigsLoading" component={ConfigsLoading} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);

export default RoutesNavigator;
```

configs_loading / index.jsx

```js
/* eslint-disable no-constant-condition */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, ActivityIndicator, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import lojas from '../../features/lojas';
import { styles } from './styles';
import pushTokens from '../../../infra/push_tokens';
import usuarios from '../../features/usuario';
import campanhas from '../../features/campanhas';

class ConfigsLoading extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#999999" />
        <Text>{this.props.t('commons:carregando')}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

ConfigsLoading.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  credenciais: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  recuperarLojaFavorita: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setarLojaCorrente: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  recuperarCredencial: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  aceitarTermosUso: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  criarTokenUsuario: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  pushToken: PropTypes.string,
  recuperarCampanhaVigente: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ConfigsLoading.defaultProps = {
  pushToken: undefined,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  salvandoLojaFavorita: lojas.selectors.obterSalvandoLojaFavorita(state),
  pushToken: pushTokens.selectors.obterToken(state),
  credenciais: usuarios.selectors.obterCredencial(state),
  aceitandoTermosUso: usuarios.selectors.obterAceitandoTermosUso(state),
  excluidoCredencialUsuario: usuarios.selectors.obterExcluindoCredencial(state),
});

const obj = translate(['common'], { wait: true })(ConfigsLoading);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  ...lojas.actions, ...pushTokens.actions, ...usuarios.actions, ...campanhas.actions,
})(obj);
```

lojas / index.js

```js
import Container from './components/Container';
import Lista from './components/Lista';
import * as constants from './constants';
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as selectors from './selectors';
import reducer from './reducer';

export default {
  Container,
  Lista,
  reducer,
  constants,
  actions,
  selectors,
};
```

pushTokens, campanhas and usuarios files has te same export as the lojas file

i have the following plugins in my babel.config.js

"babel-plugin-module-resolver",
"react-native-reanimated/plugin"

Comment: I think that package directories changed slightly: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/upgrading-from-4.x/ . I think your issue is @react-navigation/native-stack'; should be @react-navigation/stack';

Comment: @ColinHale The error keeps happening with @react-navigation/native-stack and @react-navigation/stack